# Get current_user['id'] if user is anonymous

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I try to get the current user id with `current_user['id']`.  I get `TypeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has not attribute __getitem__` even though I use `current_user.is_authenticated()` in the template and show a message if the user is not authenticated.  On other methods when I don't use `current_user['id']` I get the  proper message if the user is not authenticated.  Why am I getting this error?

```
def patients(self):
    get_doctor_id = str(current_user['id']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `User` (and `AnonymousUser`) object is not subscriptable, you don't access its attributes with `[]` notation.  Simply access the `id` directly: `current_user.id`.  Flask-Login's `UserMixin` provides a [`get_id`](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#your-user-class) method as well: `current_user.get_id()`, which by default returns `id` for authenticated users, or `None` for anonymous users.

Make sure to set up your User classes properly.

```
from flask_login import UserMixin, AnonymousUserMixin, LoginManager

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...

class AnonymousUser(AnonymousUserMixin):
    id = None  # add an id attribute to the default AnonymousUser

login_manager = LoginManager(app)
login_manager.anonymous_user = AnonymousUser
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to raise a custom error message when the current_used is anonymous, you might want to use a `try: except:` branch like so

```
def patients(self):
    try:
        get_doctor_id = str(current_user['id'])
    except TypeError:
        return flask.redirect("http://www.example.com/your/error/page/here", code=302)
```